# Refactoring techniques for data access layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I've got a data access layer to which I am binding some controls. Currently I have something along the lines of

```
   public List<Race> GetRaces()
        {
            List<Race> raceList = new List<Race>();
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetRace",con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Race r = new Race();
                        r.RaceId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["raceId"]);
                        r.RaceDescription = rdr["RaceDescription"].ToString();
                        raceList.Add(r);
                    }
                }
                return raceList;
            }
        }
        public List<Ses> GetSes()
        {
            List<Ses> sesList = new List<Ses>();
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetSes",con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Ses s = new Ses();
                        s.SesId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["SesId"]);
                        s.SesDescription = rdr["SesDescription"].ToString();
                        sesList.Add(s);
                    }
                }
                return sesList;
            }
        }
```

which will be bound to drop down lists in my presentation layer.  Instead of having to type the lion's share of this ADO.NET code over and over, what are some useful refactoring techniques for this basic type of data access?  Can I do this by refactoring with a SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and one of my custom types `Race/Ses` as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public enum SqlCommandNames
    {
        spGetRace,
        spGetSes ,
        spGetOthers
    }

public class myobj{
  public int id {get;set;}
  public string description {get;set}
}
public List<myobj> GetObj(SqlCommandNames sqlcmd)
        {
            List<myobj> objList = new List<myobj>();
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd.ToString(),con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        myobj r = new myobj();
                        r.id =  = reader.GetInt32(0); 
                        r.description = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? "" : reader.GetString(1);
                        objList.Add(r);
                    }
                }
                return objList;
            }
        }
```

Additional advice will be to cache lists

```
  List<myobj> objList = (List<myobj>)HttpContext.Current.Cache[sqlcmd.ToString()];
   if (objList == null)
     {
       List<myobj> objList = new List<myobj>();
       HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(sqlcmd.ToString(), objList);

       ....
       ....
    }


 //and  caching all  on start up


 protected void Application_Start()
        { 
            foreach (SqlCommandNames x in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SqlCommandNames)))
            {
                GetObj(x);
            } 
        }
```

Comment: This looks like I nice solution, when I get a chance to test it I'll be giving you a +1.  Thanks.